# Remove every element from multidimensional array, where second key is equal to a variable

Tags: php, arrays

Let's pressume I have the following array in php:

```
Array (
 0 => Array(
  1 => 1,
  4 => 1
 ),
 1 => Array(
  0 => 1,
  2 => 1,
  5 => 1
 ),
 2 => Array(
  1 => 1,
  6 => 1
 )
)
```

Is there any built-in php function, which can remove every element from this arrays sub-array, which has a key of 1? The result array I would need looks something like this:

```
Array (
 0 => Array(
  4 => 1
 ),
 1 => Array(
  0 => 1,
  2 => 1,
  5 => 1
 ),
 2 => Array(
  6 => 1
 )
)
```

I know that this is achiavable with a `foreach` loop, but I am looking for a one liner function if there is one. Performance wise, I would like to avoid foreach if possible. This function would be run ~2.000.000 times.

**USE CASE:** The use case for this, is would be to build a graph for a `Dijkstra` algorithm, for pathfinding purposes on a 3x3 grid, where diagonal move is not performed, and each move costs the same. I were thinking that by prepopulating a movement graph with each possible move, and then removing every path that has a blockage on it, would be faster, then by populating the graph by zero, based on the blockages.

Here's the code I use to populate the graph so far:

```
    $graph = array();
    foreach (self::$dijkstraPathCycle as $i => $possibleMoves) {
        $graph[$i] = array();
        foreach ($possibleMoves as $pos) {
            if ($this->getMonsterOnPosition($pos) !== false) continue;
            $graph[$i][self::dijkstraConvertPosToInt($pos)] = 1;
        }
    }
```

`self::$dijkstraPathCycle` is an array, that contains all the possible moves from all the possible positions. `$this->getMonsterOnPosition()` returns false if the position is empty, thus it is movable to, and `self::dijkstraConvertPosToInt()` excepts an array simmilar to `array(x,y)` as a position, and converts it to an integer using bitwise operators.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any one-liner would have to internally loop over the array in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to iterate the array, using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove elements with a key of `1`.

```
$array2 = array_map(function ($v) { 
    return array_filter($v, function ($k) {
        return $k != 1; 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    },
    $array);
print_r($array2);
```

It might be faster to use a simple foreach loop though:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    if (isset($arr[1])) unset($arr[1]);
}
```

Output (for both cases):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [4] => 1 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 1 [5] => 1 )
    [2] => Array ( [6] => 1 ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/07750)

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?